# PySpark speed Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: linux, windows, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a sample job for PySpark which is a version of the PageRank algorithm.
The code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from operator import add
import timeit
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Normalize a list of pairs(url, rank) to 1
def normalize(ranks):
    norm = sum([rank for u, rank in ranks])
    ranks = [(u, rank / norm) for (u, rank) in ranks ]
    return sorted(ranks, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

def pagerank_2(edgeList, n, niter):
    # Loads all URLs from input file and initialize their neighbors.
    m = edgeList.groupByKey().cache()
    s = 0.85

    # Loads all URLs with other URL(s) link to from input file 
    # and initialize ranks of them to one.
    q = spark.sparkContext.range(n).map(lambda x: (x, 1.0)).cache()
    r = spark.sparkContext.range(n).map(lambda x: (x, 0.0)).cache()

    # Calculates and updates URL ranks continuously 
    # using PageRank algorithm.
    for iteration in range(niter):
        # Calculates URL contributions to the rank of other URLs.
        # Add URL ranks based on neighbor contributions.
        # Do not forget to add missing values in q and set to 0.0
        q = q.fullOuterJoin(m)\
             .flatMap(lambda x: (x[1][1] and [(u, x[1][0]/len(x[1][1])) for u in x[1][1]]) or [])\
             .reduceByKey(add)\
             .rightOuterJoin(r)\
             .mapValues(lambda x: (x[0] or 0)*s + (1-s))
        print("iteration = ", iteration)

    # Collects all URL ranks and dump them to console after normalization
    ranks = normalize(q.collect())
    print(ranks[0:10])


if __name__ == "__main__":

    spark = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .master('local[*]')\
            .appName("SparkPageRank")\
            .config('spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts', 'true')\
            .config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir', 'file:///C:/Home/Org/BigData/python/BE4/') \
            .config('spark.sql.shuffle.partitions', '10')\
            .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')

    g = [(0, 1), (0, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3),
         (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 0), (5, 0), (5, 2)]
    n = 6
    edgeList = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(g)
    print(timeit.timeit('pagerank_2(edgeList, 6, 10)', number=1, globals=globals()))
```

Nodes are numbered from 0 to n-1. The edgeList parameter is an RDD holding a list of pairs of nodes (aka edges).

I run it on Windows 10 (Anaconda, Spark 2.1.0, winutils) in local mode. 
This job is distributed as 2896 tasks which are all very light.

My problem is the run time.
With the example above:

- Windows 10: >40mn !
- Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu 14.04): 30s

The computer is a laptop core i7-4702HQ, 16Gb ram, 512Gb SSD.
Windows is slower than Linux when it comes to launching process, but 50x slower?  There is surely something to do to reduce this gap?

I have disabled Windows Defender for all the files that are at stake: java directory, python directory, etc. 
Any other idea about what to look at?

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: The raw conclusion about this observation is that PySpark for Windows is probably using heavily CreateProcess() (win32 call) whereas PySpark for Linux is using fork(). CreateProcess() is very resource demanding and threads must be preferred whenever possible. It is also possible that Java is launched in a suboptimal way from Python.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the key is **local[*]** which mean that

> Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your
>   machine.

Trying to use such as **local[10]**

Comment: I don't think so. There are 8 cores on this machine, so close to 10. And anyway, the same parameters apply for Windows and Ubuntu/WSL.